# Robolectric onCreate with savedInstanceState that contains ViewHierarchyState, FragmentManagerState

Tags: android, robolectric

Using Robolectric, how can we test the recreation of an Activity that will simulate the case where Android is **recreating** the activity in response to a Back button (after the activity was destroyed by Android for RAM pressure)?

On a device, the steps to reproduce this recreation of an Activity are:

- turn on "Do not keep activities" in developer settings
- navigate to an activity in your app
- use the notification bar to bring up the Settings activity or other activity on top of your activity, which will cause your activity to be destroyed by Android as a simulation of RAM pressure
- use the Back button to dismiss the overlapping (Settings) activity

As a result of the last step with the Back button, your activity gets an onCreate() with a non-null saveInstanceState that contains information including an instance of Bundle with key "android:viewHierarchyState" and, if fragments are used, an instance of FragmentManagerState with key "android:support:fragments".

How can we simulate this in Robolectric?  We assume that we could do this with ActivityController.create(Bundle) if we can set up the Bundle appropriately.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to do this as an integration test instead.

Answer (score 3):

My pair figured it out!  Use saveInstanceState() to ask Android to populate the bundle you need:

```
    ActivityController<SearchActivity> controller = ActivityController.of(SearchActivity.class);
    controller.create().start().resume().visible().get();
    Bundle outState = new Bundle();
    controller.pause().saveInstanceState(outState).stop();

    controller = ActivityController.of(SearchActivity.class).create(outState).start().visible();
    subject = controller.get();

    // the create(Bundle) method was just called with the complete view hierarchy and fragment information
```